# How to build dynamic where in EF 6 query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

How to dynamically filter the results received from the EF.
I'm using EF 6. In previous versions of the EF it is very hard.
Maybe something has changed?
I know I can use filters, one after another, but it is not the most efficient way.
Is there a way to do it efficiently and elegantly with the EF 6.
On the internet I found a lot of information but they relate to previous versions of EF.

Comment: What is the specific question? This seems very broad. Have you used Linq?

Comment: What do you mean by efficient? What exactly do you mean by "hard"? Why do your examples for "previous versions" not work?

Answer (score 1):

I would be using the IQueryable linq interface to build up the necessary filters that you require.

something very basic like

```
public IEnumerable<Orders> Orders(int? customerNumber){
  var query = dbContext.Orders;

  if (customerNumber.hasValue)
  {
    query = query.Where(c=>c.Id == customerNumber.value)
  }
  return query.ToList();

}
```